# Puppeteer: How to select a dropdown option based on its text?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

In Puppeteer, we can select an option of a dropdown by providing the value as a parameter:

```
page.select('select#idOfSelect', 'optionValue');
```

Is there a function to select an option based on its text and not from its value?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no such method in Puppeteer API. But you can select `option` based on a text with XPath, then extract the value of this element and pass this value to `page.select()`. Here is a full example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const html = `
        <html>
            <body>
                <select id="selectId">
                    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select>
            </body>
        </html>`;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  const option = (await page.$x(
    '//*[@id = "selectId"]/option[text() = "Audi"]'
  ))[0];
  const value = await (await option.getProperty('value')).jsonValue();
  await page.select('#selectId', value);

  await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the [`option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement) you would like to select by its [`text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement#Properties) property. Then you can use the [`selected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement#Properties) property to indicate that the option is currently selected:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const example = document.querySelector('#example');
  const example_options = example.querySelectorAll('option');
  const selected_option = [...example_options].find(option => option.text === 'Hello, world!');

  selected_option.selected = true;
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: You can reduce this by one line using `const options = document.querySelectorAll('#example option')`

Answer (score 9):

$$eval is probably a bit cleaner than these other answers:

```
let optionValue = await page.$$eval('option', options => options.find(o => o.innerText === "foo")?.value)
await page.select('select#idOfSelect', optionValue);
```

Comment: thanks. this is a single-line solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use page.evaluate() and go directly to the element you want.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    $("#idOfSelect option:contains('your-text')")[0].selected = true
})
```

Though this will thrown an error if your element it's not present, so you should ensure if the element actually exists before you select it..

Comment: This is jQuery only.